# ArangoDB FULLTEXT() search partial match does not work for substrings

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am running a simple query similar to the following:

```
FOR node IN FULLTEXT("myCollection", "myAttribute", "abcdef") 
    RETURN node
```

I have a node in myCollection with myAttribute == "abcdef" and myAttribute has a fulltext index on it and the above query works just fine and returns one result. However the following query returns no result:

```
FOR node IN FULLTEXT("myCollection", "myAttribute", "abcde") 
    RETURN node
```

The examples in the documentation search for the word "the" in a sentence so I expect that a FULLTEXT() search for "abcde" should match "abcdef". Can someone explain to me what I am missing or what needs to be done to make FULLTEXT("myCollection", "myAttribute", "abcde") find my node where myAttribute == "abcdef".

Thanks!

-- Update: I oversimplified the above query to try and keep it short and understandable. I should have provided a sample query such as:

```
 FOR node IN FULLTEXT("myCollection", "myAttribute", "bcde") 
    RETURN node
```

to demonstrate what I am trying to do and what does not work. Does ArangoDB support substring searches using indices in any fashion. I am trying to add a text search to my application and am afraid that using LIKE will result in a full collection scan on every collection on multiple fields (case insensitive) and will not scale. This post is really about how to do a performant text search accross multiple collections (and many, but not all attributes) in the database.

Sorry for the oversimplification. Hopefully this is clearer. Is there a good way of implementing a "search" in ArangoDB that will support the search semantics users expect when they enter a search string in a search box?

Answer (score 3):

because Fulltext searches for the whole word not part of it.

you should use **"prefix:"** before the word.

```
FOR node IN FULLTEXT("myCollection", "myAttribute", "prefix:abcde") 
    RETURN node
```

this query should work , for more reference and another functions : [Fulltext functions](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Functions/Fulltext.html)

Comment: Sorry, I over simplified my example. I am also searching for "bcd" and substrings. I take this to mean that substring searches using indexing is not supported?

Comment: The fulltext index can only be used for full and prefix matches. Substring matches require a full collection scan, e.g. `FOR node IN myCollection FILTER node.myAttribute LIKE "%bcd%" RETURN node`. This will match "bcde", "abcd" as well as "abcde".

Comment: Thanks. I started to gather as much. I updated my post to clarify what I am trying to do. I was hoping for something more performant than the full collection scans required by LIKE

Comment: P.S. I found the following post (yours?): https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/217 about this, but no followup on changes in the last year. Unlike your example I am scanning millions of documents and want something more responsive for the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to find substrings, consider using [`CONTAINS`](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/AQL/Functions/String.html#contains) instead of [`LIKE`](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/AQL/Functions/String.html#like) .

I ran each of these ten times for a simple comparison using the word `foo` as needle:

```
// This query took ca. 20-22ms:
FOR t IN texts
    FILTER LIKE(t.text, '%foo%', true)
    RETURN KEEP(t, 'text', 'create_time')

// This query took ca 4-6 ms:
FOR t IN texts
    FILTER CONTAINS(t.text, 'foo')
    RETURN KEEP(t, 'text', 'create_time')
```

**Note** that `CONTAINS` is case-sensitive, whereas the third parameter to `LIKE` makes case-insensitivity an option.

To get around this I would either add [`LOWER`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.3/AQL/Functions/String.html#lower) as below, or if it's possible: pre-process the text before inserting it into the database.

```
// This query took ca 11-13 ms:
FOR t IN texts
    FILTER CONTAINS(LOWER(t.text), 'foo')
    RETURN KEEP(t, 'text', 'create_time')
```

[This issue](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/1796) might be relevant, which is related to this question: [On multiple index usage in ArangoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587746/on-multiple-index-usage-in-arangodb).

(I actually used a non-English word and not `foo` as needle, but that's irrelevant.)